# Paging without Entity Framework?

Tags: paging

I wrote a MVC C# application which is using a database without Entity Framework.
I want to add a paging to my application - most examples of paging I found are using Entity Framework. Can someone point me to examples of paging without EF?

Thanks,

ZB

Comment: How are you connecting to your database? ado.net?

Answer (score 2):

I just found solution which works for me:

```
 List<NumberUI> allPages = _repository.GetAllPages();
 int pageSize = 10;
 int totalUserCount = allPages.Count();
 IPagedList<NumberUI> allPagebleNumbers = allPages.ToPagedList(pageNo, pageSize);
 return View(allPagebleNumbers);
```

zb